# $watchCollection isn't working correctly

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently trying to bind a value to a scope and then watch it, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. The $watch is never fired. Service.info object and isn't apart of the scope or anything. The service is also the one causing the changes to info and not the Controller with the $watch. Might that causing the issue?

```
// Service code
function() {
    var info = {
        prop: false
    };

    window.addEventListener('offline', function() {
        info.prop = !info.prop;
    }, false);

    return {
        info: info
    };
}

// Controller code
$scope.info = Service.info;
$scope.$watchCollection('info', function(newValue) {
    if (newValue.prop) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

Comment: How deep are your changes to `info` nested and what kind of changes are you expecting? `$watchCollection` is not watching as deep as `$watch(..,true)`.

Comment: Show us the code that modifies the info. If it's doing `Service.info = someNewArray`, it's normal that the watch doesn't fire, since $scope.info is left unmodified.

Comment: I've updated my example to have the service code. I only want to watch the values of the properties changing in info, not anything deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. Turns out that the Controller I was calling this in was nested in an `ng-if`. Therefore, if the `ng-if` equated to false and didn't render the DOM element that the Controller was associated with, the `$scope` I was watching on didn't actually exist.

Comment: Darn, I thought I just solved your problem.. Just worked on a demo using a service to simulate a change on info.prop. :P oh well. It's available on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrRampage/2CtCq/) if it'll help you in the future.

Answer (score 5):

## Cause

The `$watchCollection` is only a [shallow watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope). So watching `info` will only look for changes in `info`'s properties. If no properties are added or changed, then the watch will not be triggered. To fix this you would need to watch `info.prop` or you could use a `$watch` and set the flag to use a deep watch - however this will be less performant.

### $watchCollection documentation

> Shallow watches the properties of an object and fires whenever any of
>   the properties change (for arrays, this implies watching the array
>   items; for object maps, this implies watching the properties). If a
>   change is detected, the listener callback is fired.

## Demo

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrRampage/8p323/)

In this demo you can see that by manipulating `info`, the `$watchCollection` on `info` is triggered. Manipulating `prop`, the `$watchCollection` on `info.prop` is triggered.

### HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ctrl">
    <pre>
        {{ info | json }}
    </pre>
    <button ng-click="change()">
        Change!
    </button>
    <button ng-click="addProp()">
        Affect info!
    </button>
</div>
```

### Controller

```
function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.info = {
        prop: {}
    };

    $scope.change = function() {
        $scope.info.prop["dog" + Math.random()] = Math.random();
    }

    $scope.addProp = function() {
        $scope.info["cat" + Math.random()] = Math.random();
    }

    $scope.$watchCollection('info.prop', function(value) {
        if (value) {
            console.log("info.prop has changed!");
        }
    });

    $scope.$watchCollection('info', function(value) {
        if (value.prop) {
            console.log("info has changed!");
        }
    });

    $scope.$watch('info', function(value) {
        if (value) {
            console.log("deep watch triggered");   
        }
    }, true);
};
```

Comment: I only have on level of properties, it doesn't go any deeper then that. It's not working with any of these options. I've updated my code to show the service that is changing the info object.